# Why is `source ~/.bash_aliases` exiting with syntax error?

Tags: bash, syntax

What is the syntax error in this file? I can't spot it.

```
set-k8s-azure() { 
  export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.azure-1 
}

set-k8s-minikube() { export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.minikube }

minikube() {
  if [[ $@ == start* ]]; then
    set-k8s-minikube
  fi
  command minikube "$@"
}

alias pulr='if output=$(git status --porcelain) && [ -z "$output" ]; then git pull --rebase; else git stash save "pulr WIP saved" && git pull --rebase && git stash pop; fi'
alias vi=nvim
```

`source ~/.bash_aliases` produces:

```
bash: /home/niel/.bash_aliases: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/niel/.bash_aliases: line 1: `set-k8s-azure() { '
```

Comment: The error should be what Kusalananda explains, but is that really the error message you see? I get `syntax error: unexpected end of file` (which is what I'd expect since the `{ }` subshell is never closed because of the missing `;`). What version of bash is this?

Comment: @terdon That is really it. "GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"

Comment: OK, that's really weird. I'm using Arch and `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` and don't get the first error.

Comment: you'd get a syntax error on the `(` if the line had whitespace in middle of the function name, like `foo bar() { ...`. But they'd need to be something the shell recognizes as whitespace. I couldn't come up with how to recreate that with invisible characters; my Bash accepts e.g. zero-width non-joiners as parts of the function name. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashes are not valid in function names. (For more details, see  [Are there problems with hyphens in functions, aliases, and executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168221/117037)) Bash is normally tolerant of certain invalid chars, but in some cases it's not, and I have no idea why, though I've [seen this before](https://askubuntu.com/a/891469/301745). So replace the dashes with underscores (and add a semicolon like Kusalananda said) and it'll be fine:

```
set_k8s_azure() { 
  export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.azure-1 
}

set_k8s_minikube() { export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.minikube; }
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, for the sake of future readers, because it summarizes the whole problem.

Comment: @NieldeWet That's seem reasonable to me.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that the syntax error is here:

```
set-k8s-minikube() { export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.minikube }
```

The `{...}` construct needs either a newline or a `;` before the final `}`:

```
set-k8s-minikube() { export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.minikube; }
```

Also, I'd advise that you use `$HOME` rather than `~` in scripts, partly because it serves as documentation and partly because `$HOME` behaves like a variable whereas `~` does not (see [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)).

Comment: Thanks, that's part of the problem. The other part, and apparently the one that is producing the syntax error I saw, is the user of the hyphen in the function name. Replacing those with underscores solves the problem.

Comment: `set_k8s_minikube() { export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config.minikube; }` works.

Comment: Hmm, function name with hyphens is OK for me on bash v4.3.48

Comment: @NieldeWet I have no old Bash to test with, unfortunately...

Comment: Apparently hyphens are not guaranteed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/are-there-problems-with-hyphens-in-functions-aliases-and-executables, although the accepted answer there claims that bash does support it.

Comment: Even the Bash 3.2.57 on my Mac supports hyphens in function names.